# IOS 8 device token not return when turn off notification setting

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

Im developing IOS push notification, and im trying to grab device token. I able to get device token when OS notification setting is turn on. When it turn off, my `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is no longer called, and hence, i unable to get device token.

here is my code

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  #ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
    //Right, that is the point
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge
                                                                                         |UIUserNotificationTypeSound
                                                                                         |UIUserNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
  #else
    //register to receive notifications
    UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
  #endif
    return YES;
}`

and i do also added

`- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings`

`- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler`

However, when turn off OS notification setting,

`- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken`

will not be called. I've debug this for many hour and found no luck.

Comment: What did you expect, notifications are turned off so you won't get this callback. This is working as designed.

Comment: i do expect i still able to get the token, as turning off notification is simply an setting. So do you mean when user first choose "Not Allow" when get prompt from OS when first install, we wont be able to get the token, until user enable the setting?  please correct me if im wrong. thank. @Lance

Comment: Yes, if the user selects "not allow" when you request push notification access it will prevent your app from getting a push token. That's how it's supposed to work.

Comment: @Lance,ive perform a testing.I first install a IM apps,and i choose "not allow" at first.I send a message to the IM,no notification popped out.And then i go to OS setting, enable the apps notification.Without launch the IM apps,i send another message to it.It able to pop me notification. My question:at first i choose "not allow", so the apps server shouldnt have my device token.However, after i enable notification setting in OS setting, without launch apps, it able to pop me notification. Since i do not launch the apps, no way apps be able to send my token after i enable in OS setting isnt it?

Comment: The majority of the time the device token doesn't change, ever. So if you got a token, sent it to your server, then disable and then re-enable notifications like you describe, it's very likely that your old token is still valid and since you enabled notifications, iOS isn't muting the notifications anymore so they show up.

Answer (score 0):

I've encounter the same problem.

Managed to solve it by enabling "Remote notifications" in project's Capabilities section (see screenshot below).

[Background mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dd8XX.png)

*My opinion on this issue:*

If user has **explicitly forbid** notifications from your application and application has **turned off "Remote notifications"**, you have no way to deliver notification to user. That's why there is no need to return token for your application.

If user has **turned off notifications**, but you **enabled "Remote notifications"**, means that you still have opportunity to send silent notifications and iOS provides token for you.